# Where are CoreLib.h,Buffer.h, Logger.h..?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Where can I find these header files on Windows 7? I just installed VS2010, but seems dont have these header..

```
CoreLib.h
#include "Buffer.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "CoreLibImpl_.h"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you expect them to be a part of Windows 7 or VS2010?

Google tells me what you're looking for is a part of [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). So go ahead and [install the source](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-WindowsSourceInstallation). If you already have them and you just can't get VS to find the files, [add them to the include directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Those names don't sound familiar. They're not one of the standard C++ headers like `<iostream>`, or the C headers like `<stdlib.h>`. Nor do they appear to be MFC headers. Why do you expect VS2010 to ship with these?